# Find A such that $A\cos(t+\theta)=\frac{1}{4}\cos(t)+\frac{1}{2}\sin(t)$

Tags: calculus, trigonometry

I need to find A such that $$A\cos(t+\theta)=\frac{1}{4}\cos(t)+\frac{1}{2}\sin(t)$$

This is how I proceed,

$$A\cos(t+\theta) = A\cos(t)\cos(\theta)-A\sin(t)sin(\theta),$$

Hence $$A\cos(t)\cos(\theta)-A\sin(t)sin(\theta) = \frac{1}{4}\cos(t)+\frac{1}{2}\sin(t),$$

That is, $$A\cos(\theta) = \frac{1}{4} $$ and $$ A\sin(\theta) = -\frac{1}{2}$$

Hence $A=\frac{\sqrt{5}}{4}$ (Is A necessarily positive?)

Comment: Excellent! You need to correct the typos in $A\cos(t)=\frac{1}{4}$ and $A\sin(t)=\frac{1}{2}$ (the $t$ should be $\theta$) and the 2nd equ needs a minus sign.

Comment: Though $A$ here is conventionally rendered as positive, it could alternatively be rendered as negative by adding $\pi$ radians to $\theta$.

Comment: Thanks @almagest just corrected the typo.

Answer (score 1):

you were right till:

$$
A \cos t \cos \theta - A \sin t\sin \theta = \frac{1}{4} \cos t + \frac{1}{2} \sin t 
$$

However, now, remember that we are comparing coefficients of $\cos t$, $\sin t$ **not** $\cos \theta$, $\sin \theta$.

Hence,

1. equating coefficients of $\cos t$,
   $$
   A \cos \theta = \frac{1}{4}
   $$
2. Equating coefficients of $\sin t$,
   $$
   A \sin \theta = \frac{1}{2}
   $$
3. Squaring both equations and adding,
   $$
   A^2 \cos^2 \theta + A^2 \sin^2 \theta = \frac{1}{4^2} + \frac{1}{2^2} \\
   A^2(\cos^2 \theta + \sin^2 \theta) = \frac{20}{64} = \frac{5}{16} \\
   A^2 = \frac{5}{16} \\
   A = \frac{\sqrt{5}}{4}
   $$

Hence, $A = \frac{\sqrt 5}{4}$

Comment: What if $\theta=0$?

Comment: that's not possible in the original inequality (since we have a $sin(t)$ term there, that cannot be present if $\theta = 0$)

Comment: Okay, but there is only one $\theta$ for which this holds. The question is not very well posed if you ask me.

Comment: yes, that is true. it's not really independent of $\theta$. However, you can still isolate $A$ which was what the question asked for. By the way, was it you who downvoted my answer? If so, what's the rationale? I'm curious,

Comment: It was me, the reason was that this makes sense for only one theta, but then I realized that that was not your fault. I tried to undo it since its obviously very harsh, but I cannot change my vote unfortunately. I hope someone else gives it an upvote to compensate.

Comment: I think it is possible to change a downvote by simply clicking on the upvote button. Could you check for me, now I'm curious.

Comment: No, but I can if you edit the question. There's a time limit involved.

Comment: @Mathematician42 - yep, I edited it.

Comment: Solved, there you go.

Answer (score 0):

Solving the above:
$$\theta=sin^{-1}\left(\frac{2}{\sqrt{5}}\right)=1.107$$

If $A=-\frac{\sqrt{5}}{4}$, then $\theta=1.107+\pi=4.249$.  This is equivalent to a $180^{\circ}$ phase shift.